# How to prevent search engines from indexing wordpress menus

Tags: php, wordpress, function, seo

I hope you can help

How can I prevent search engines such as Google from indexing wordpress menus. When I say menus I am referring to the text (word/s) within the link not the actual link itself.

Example: `<a href="http://mywebsite.com"> Home Page </a>` How can I prevent indexing/showing the words (Home Page) in search engine results.

No plugins please

Thanks

Comment: the old trck-move them to the bottom of the html page, but use css to make them appear at the top

Comment: Don't do that, because it's black-hat SEO. You will only harm your website. Google is not that stupid. You need to have some anchor text in order for link to be valid.

Comment: @BojanMiljevic i have seen no evidence that this is true: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/58238/hiding-menu-item-with-css-will-google-penalise-my-site. but if you have some please share

Comment: @Dagon I don't see why anyone would hide the anchor text of the links from Google. SEO juice is transferred over them and anchor text is an important part. If you don't want them to appear in Google results, just write a proper meta description. Google will understand that these links belong to navigation and will treat them accordingly. Regarding hiding elements using CSS, you can find numerous articles on that all over the Internet, like http://www.seobythesea.com/2013/03/google-invisible-text-hidden-links/. If jack would explain the idea behind hiding the links, I might be able to help.

Comment: @BojanMiljevic The reason for removing the text because Google is indexing the word Home Page despite the presence of meta descriptions/titles etc, I am trying to not to have words such as Home Page, Contact, About etc from being indexed in Google. I am not interested in any black-hat SEO. Thanks

Comment: Can you, please, add a link to your website, to I can check?